# Set Cell Value Null When User Selects A Specific cell in a Column

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2007, i'm trying to accomplish the following through VBA code:

1. In Col-A, if the value is aa, bb, cc then values in Col-E should be updated to 100, 1000, 10000 respectively.
2. If the value in Col-E is 10000 then the font color in the cell should be greyed-out. (the VBA code below is performing the details in step - 1, 2)

Here is where I'm struck:

a. In Col-A, user selects value "cc", Col-E in the row updates to "10000" and the font is greyed-out.

b. When the user selects the cell in Col-E which has "10000" then, the contents in the specific cell should be cleared. If the user enters any value then, the value entered by user should be retained. Else if the user does not enter any value and navigates to another cell, then "10000" and the font is greyed-out should appear

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)   
   Dim LastRow As Long    
   Dim i As Long 

   LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 2 To LastRow
      If Range("A" & i).Value = "aa" Then
         Range("E" & i).Value = "100"
         ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      End If
   Next i

   For i = 2 To LastRow
      If Range("A" & i).Value = "bb" Then
         Range("E" & i).Value = "1000"
         ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      End If
   Next i

   For i = 2 To LastRow
      If Range("A" & i).Value = "cc" Then
         Range("E" & i).Value = "10000"
         ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
      End If
   Next i    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide excel with a few more info and directions than what you have done up till now. To accomplish your goal I added some extra lines to your script and it works for me.

```
    Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim i As Long

        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim blnUserActive As Boolean
        blnUserActive = False
        Dim rngActive As Range
        Set rngActive = Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
        If Not (Application.Intersect(rngActive, Target) Is Nothing) And Target.Value = "10000" Then
            'user has clicked in Column E and the value there is 10000
            blnUserActive = True
            Target.Value = ""
        End If

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If Range("A" & i).Value = "aa" Then
               Range("E" & i).Value = "100"
               ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next i

        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If Range("A" & i).Value = "bb" Then
               Range("E" & i).Value = "1000"
               ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next i


        For i = 2 To LastRow
            ' the following two lines tells the loop to ignore this step if proven true
            If Range("E" & i).Value <> "" And Range("E" & i).Value <> "10000" Then GoTo IgnoreEntry
            If blnUserActive Then GoTo IgnoreEntry

            If Range("A" & i).Value = "cc" Then
               Range("E" & i).Value = "10000"
               ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
            End If
IgnoreEntry:
        Next i
```

I hope this solves your problem. Cheers.